# obtain the MAC Address/interface name from GUI on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ethernet

Is there any way I can obtain the MAC Address/interface name from GUI on FreeBSD?
Are there any system calls to do that?
I was searching everywhere but couldn't find any information.
Can you please help?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards,
Marc.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're looking for a GUI way to do this but you can get the MAC Address from the command line like so:

```
$ ifconfig em0
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU>
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fefd:f61d%em0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 198.18.152.169 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 198.18.255.255
        ether 00:0c:29:fd:f6:1d
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```

The MAC Address is the string after the word "ether", 00:0c:29:fd:f6:1d. You can see all the network devices with this command:

```
$ ifconfig -a
```

see the [ifconfig](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig&sektion=8) man page for more info.

#### Example

```
ifconfig em0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'
00:0c:29:fd:f6:1d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This was helpful. I was more looking for a programmatic way to get the details.

Comment: See the example I added to my answer. You can adjust it to suite your needs.

Comment: Useless use of grep: `ifconfig em0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`